# ZEUS Uranium-Calorimeter

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-detectors

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZEUS_%28particle_detector%29):

> In the ZEUS calorimeter neutral pions interacted with uranium atoms to produce slow moving neutrons which were captured by the scintillator and increased the hadronic signal.

The way I read it out, this is not given for every scintillator. Why did the use of Uranium lead to the possibility to detect neutrons in the plastic scintillators of the ZEUS experiment?

Comment: Because it reacts with the neutral pions yielding some neutrons.

Comment: Okay, why does Uranium react with the neutral pions whereas brass (used at CMS) doesn't? :)

Comment: Perhaps more a cross section question. A quick glance at literature indicates U has a substantially higher cross section than Au or Bi to pions, much less Cu.

Comment: Hmm, what kind of literature did you consult? xD

Comment: A quick Web of Science search pointed to some Phys. Rev. C articles and I scanned their abstracts.